# How to correctly prompt a user for input until they give a valid response

Tags: c, io, getchar

I want to print a prompt message to standard output, and then read 
a value from standard input entered by the user (for example, a digit).

If the user entered an invalid value, I want to print the prompt again, and
read their response again, until they enter a valid value (kind of like how
[shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29#Text_.28CLI.29_shells) work).

The problem is that when the user enters an invalid value, the prompt somehow
gets printed twice, which is not what I want.

Here is what I've tried so far, unsuccessfully:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *prompt = "(Enter 1 to continue)> ";

int get_resp1(void)
{
    int r;
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
    r = getchar() - '0';
    if (r != 1)
        r = get_resp1();
    return r;
}

int get_resp2(void)
{
    int r;
    r = getchar() - '0';
    if (r != 1) {
        fputs(prompt, stdout);
        r = get_resp2();
    }
    return r;
}

int get_resp3(void)
{
    int r;
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
    do {
        r = getchar() - '0';
        if (r != 0)
            fputs(prompt, stdout);
    } while (r != 1);

    return r;
}

int main(void)
{
    int response;
    /* First attempt: */
    /* response = get_resp1(); */

    /* Second attempt */
    /* fputs(prompt, stdout); */
    /* response = get_resp2(); */

    /* Third attempt: */
    /* response = get_resp3(); */

    return response != 1;
}
```

Here's the result I want:

```
(Enter 1 to continue)> 2
(Enter 1 to continue)>
(Enter 1 to continue)> 1
```

*In the first line, we enter something other than 1, in the second
line, we enter a blank line, then finally, we enter 1.*

But here is the result I am getting (using all three methods):

```
(Enter 1 to continue)> 2
(Enter 1 to continue)> (Enter 1 to continue)>
(Enter 1 to continue)> 1
```

*Notice the prompt is printed twice in the second line.*

Comment: Once for the input character and next time for `\n`

Comment: @coderredoc But how can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Consume all those whitespace character and then again wait for correct input.

Comment: If I consume the `\n`, then it wouldn't print the prompt if the user types an empty response (like in the second line).

Comment: You can consume the whole line using `fgets()` and then process each line accordingly. That way in case of multiple character input you can discard it. Suppose use input `>> 2341` then it should discard it. You want `>> 1` and then it will be accepted.

Comment: @coderredoc Thank's, that worked. I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is being said, if the input contains the value `1` (with zero or more spaces or tabs) then it will be accepted. Any other combination of character will be discarded.

You can change the code to change the behavior. And this is just an attempt to demo the OP with a similar kind of processing as expected by the OP in the question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAXBUFFSIZE 100
bool getConfirmation(){
    printf("\n%s",">> ");
    char buff[MAXBUFFSIZE];
    unsigned int success = 0;
    while( 1 ){
        success = 0;
        if( fgets(buff,MAXBUFFSIZE,stdin) == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error in input");
            break;
        }

        for( size_t i = 0;  i < strlen(buff); i++){
            if(isspace(buff[i]))
                continue;
            else if( isalpha(buff[i]))
                break;
            else if( isdigit(buff[i]) ){
                if( buff[i] == '1'){
                    success++;
                    if( success > 1)
                        break;
                }
                else{
                    success = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if( success == 1 )
            break;
        success =  0;
        printf("\n%s",">> ");
    }
    if( success == 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}
int main(){

    if( getConfirmation() == true )
        printf("%s\n","Continued ... ");
    else
        printf("%s\n","Error in input");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `fgets`:

```
int get_resp4(void)
{
    int r;
    char buf[0x7f];
    char *ptr = buf;
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);

    while (*ptr && *ptr != '\n' && !isdigit(*ptr))
        ++ptr;
    if (!isdigit(*ptr))
        r = get_resp4();
    else
        r = *ptr - '0';

    if (r != 1)
        r = get_resp4();

    return r;
}
```

Comment: what this is supposed to do? How do you call it? What happens when user give wrong input?

Comment: Just like in the question. You call it like this: `response = get_resp4();`. It doesn't really do anything because it either returns 1 or keeps calling itself. This is just an example. And that's exactly what I wanted it to do.

Comment: But in case there are many errors it may end up eating yor stack due to too many calls. Check my answer or try it once.